# How to compare the derived objects from a base class in java?

Tags: java, class, oop, polymorphism

I have a *Base* class and two classes are derived from the *Base* class namely *Derived1* and *Derived2*, I want to check whether *object* is of type *Derived1* or *Derived2*.

This is my code:

```
public class Base {
    int ID;
}

public class Derived1 extends Base {
    int subID;
}

public class Derived2 extends Base {
    int subID;
}

public class Program(){
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Base object = new Derived1();

        // I want to check whether "object" is of type Derived1 or Derived2
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to change functionality based on the state of your object, you might want to consider letting the sub classes handle that functionality by using an `@Override` on a abstract method declared in the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object.getClass() == Derived1.class` would return true. As would `object instanceof Derived1`. `object.getClass().getName()` would return `"com.foo.Derived1"`. `Derived1 = (Derived1) object;` would either work, or throw `ClassCastException`.

Those are your main 3 options.

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks!
btw, is any one of them more efficient than others or all are equally efficient?

Comment: they're all equal.